# p tag text goes behind page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The scr shows my problem. Basically post.body is wrapped with p tag. Body content goes behind the page only when added text was typed manually(not copy/paste)
[image]

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9">
       <h4><%= @post.title %></h4>
           <p><small>by <%= @user.username %>, <%= time(@post) %></small></p>
           <p><%= @post.body %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <!-- <div class="pull-right"> -->
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt=""><br/>
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>      
  </div>
```

up

When I just copy some text(not typing by hands) I have this
[image]

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent spaceless text going under the content of the next column, force lines wrap with `word-break` rule:

```
p {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mRgD1Cw3plqBwBHxwCy1?p=preview

<sub>In the demo hover over the text to see how `word-break` helps.</sub>